# List to Pandas DF Read as Strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I am working on a project and would like to use/learn pandas since it seems very powerful for what I am trying to do....

***CONSTRAINTS*** I cannot change the fact that I have python code reading in multiple files to construct the dictionary. This is how is has to be and I must live with it and create the dataframe from that dictionary of lists.

**Problem 1:** I am getting dictionary passed to me. The dictionary contains multiple numerical items. Each item contains a list of data. This data has a time field that I am trying to compute the difference of between each row. Right now I am reading in a single numerical item, transposing it to get it into the correct structure and then trying to perform the .diff() operation on it... For example...

```
'400' : [ [ {'IDs'} ], {'TIME COL'}, ... ]
```

I then do the following command...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(myData['400'])
```

which I then do the transpose of such that all my time's are now in rows and not in columns.

**Question 1:** Is this the correct way of doing it? Since I want to take the difference of the time, I was reading that the diff works on rows and not columns. If this is not correct how should I be doing it?

**Problem 2:** So for now the transpose works... However, when I try to do the diff operation on any column I get the following error...

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

**Question 2:** Am I reading the data in wrong? Should I be doing something else to convert it such that it recognizes it as a integer dataset so I can do this operation?

Any insight is welcome!

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you resolve your issue as you need to convert your dates into `pandas datetime`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': list('ABC'), 'Col2': ['1/1/2017', '1/2/2017', '1/3/2017'], 'Col3': ['1/1/2016', '1/2/2016', '1/3/2016']})
df[['Col2', 'Col3']] = df[['Col2', 'Col3']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
df['Col4'] = df['Col2'] - df['Col3']
```

This is just an example as you didn't share any actual data.